# Why does std::package_task fails to be called on GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, packaged-task

Following code is ok on Microsoft and Clang compilers but fails on GCC. It throws `std::system_error` with message `-1`. Is it know issue?

```
#include <future>

int main() 
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> task([](){});
    task();
}
```

[GCC](http://rextester.com/live/ALPY16046)

[Clang](http://rextester.com/live/HXKO2584)

[Visual C++](http://rextester.com/live/LDFPK72435)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link with `-lpthread`, otherwise there is no thread support the C++ run-time library could use.  This has been reported as a GCC bug:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59830

I agree that the usability here is quite poor.  There is also a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790363/c-core-dump-with-packaged-task).