# c++ std::packaged_task call throws system exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, exception, packaged-task

I've got a very simple code snippet from cpprefernce.com, as follows:

```
#include<future>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    packaged_task<int(int)> t([](int i){return i+1;});
    auto f = t.get_future();
    cout<<"begin to call t\n";
    t(3);
    cout<<f.get()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Once I run it with g++ on ubuntu18.04, it prints:

```
begin to call t
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Unknown error -1
Aborted
```

So where does the program get wrong, how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get this point?

Comment: Can't reproduce error here. Introduce a delay before calling f.get() or check f for readiness since future<int> may not be ready then.

Comment: The problem disappears when compiling with `-lpthread` flag. Tested on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc8083afbf635dc7). Try to build without `-lpthread` and see what happens.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790363/c-core-dump-with-packaged-task/41790617

Comment: Thanks for this link, problem is solved by using "-pthread" not "-lpthread" as linker flag.